# Whats the difference between the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF 3) and Chromium Content API in the context of browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, frameworks, chromium, chromium-embedded

In the use case of building a browser, both seem like tools that could be used to mock up a UI for a chromium browser. Besides CEF being vastly better documented, whats the difference between the two for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Most APIs around Chromium provides the stable API and/or ABI that Google refuses to provide with their layer. By using CEF, QtWebEngine or any of the other wrappers, you don't have your code break all the time, plus the code actually compiles out of the box, which Chromium sources rarely does except for the *exact* configuration Google compiles.